# Redux, "delete Object" is not working properly in nested Object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux

Redux, "delete Object" is not working properly in nested Object. I am just trying to delete key "b" in key "0". I am able to just delete the key "0", but when I am trying to delete the nested key "b" in "0", is not working. If you have any idea how to solve it, please, let me know!

Code:

```
export function removeOrder(key1, key2) {
  return {
    type: 'REMOVE_ORDER',
    payload: {key1: key1, key2: key2},
  };
}

var initialState = {
  0: {
    a: {
      title: 'aa',
    },
    b: {
      title: 'bb',
    },
    c: {
      title: 'cc',
    },
  },

  1: {
    a: {
      title: 'aa',
    },
    b: {
      title: 'bb',
    },
    c: {
      title: 'cc',
    },
  },
};

function ordersReducer(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'REMOVE_ORDER':
      const id1 = action.payload.id1;
      const id2 = action.payload.id2;

      // Working
      //delete state[id1];

      // Not working
      delete state[id1][id2];

      return state;
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

removeOrder(0, 'a');
```

The expected result:

```
{
  0: {
    b: {
      title: 'bb',
    },
    c: {
      title: 'cc',
    },
  },

  1: {
    a: {
      title: 'aa',
    },
    b: {
      title: 'bb',
    },
    c: {
      title: 'cc',
    },
  },
};
```

Comment: once you've `delete state[id1]` it can't exist for you to `delete state[id1][id2]` - and there's absolutely no point in deleting the inner object then the outer one, since you're deleting the outer one anyway

Comment: I mean if I only use "delete state[id1][id2]" without "delete state[id1]", it is not deleting the nested object.

Comment: perhaps you meant `const id1 = action.payload.key1; const id2 = action.payload.key2;` since that's what the action object looks like? or maybe `payload: {id1: key1, id2: key2},` since that's what the function expects? looks like a simple typo - note `delete obj[undefined]` does not throw an error - which is why `delete state[id1];` didn't throw an error  even though it did nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't `delete` a field from state like that, as that would mutate the actual `state` object which is one of the basic no-no's in Redux. From their docs:

> https://redux.js.org/usage/troubleshooting#never-mutate-reducer-arguments
> It is tempting to modify the state or action passed to you by Redux. Don't do this!

For general patterns see [immutable-update-patterns](https://redux.js.org/usage/structuring-reducers/immutable-update-patterns). Specifically for your example you need to create a new state object, spreading the values you do want... An easy way to do this is to use lodash's [omitBy](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#omitBy) to exclude the item with the particular key that you don't want in there anymore.

```
function ordersReducer(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'REMOVE_ORDER':
      const id1 = action.payload.id1; 
      return omitBy(state, (value, key) => key === id1);
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

As others have mentioned in the comments, you can ignore `id2` if it's just a sub-key of `id1`.

If you just want to remove a subkey of `id1` then you could use this instead, which is a slight modification on the same approach:

```
function ordersReducer(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'REMOVE_ORDER':
      const id1 = action.payload.id1; 
      const id2 = action.payload.id2;
      
      return {
          ...state,
          [id1]: omitBy(state, (value, key) => key === id2)
      };

    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Comment: I think OP wants to remove key1.key2 or even something that is nested deeper so a recursive remove is needed.

Comment: @HMR maybe, that wasn't clear. I'll expand my answer to cover that :)

Answer (score 0):

As Bravo points out, once you delete the "root" property then all nested properties are also removed.

Other than property deletion you've a state mutation issue since you delete a property and then return the same state object.

You need to return a new copy of state, then you can use a single delete referencing the "full" dynamic path to the second nested key.

```
case 'REMOVE_ORDER':
  const { key1, key2 } = action.payload;

  // shallow copy state
  const nextState = { ...state };

  if (state[key1]) {
    // shallow copy the nested state
    nextState[key1] = { ...state[key1] }
  }

  // delete the nested property if it exists
  delete nextState[key1]?.[key2]; 

  return nextState;
```

Comment: I think OP wants to remove key1.key2 or even a dynamic amount of keys. A solution could be to make it recursive.

Comment: @HMR It may be more productive to leave a comment to the OP asking for clarification over spamming the comments of other answers.  Also, think I see what you mean. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should not mutate state, you can use [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) you don't need to add extra dependencies to your project, omit would be a couple of lines of code:

```js
function omit(state, keys) {
  const { [keys[0]]: remove, ...rest } = state;
  if (keys.length === 1) {
    return rest;
  }
  return {
    ...state,
    [keys[0]]: omit(remove, keys.slice(1)),
  };
}

//test code:
const state = {
  0: {
    b: {
      title: 'bb',
    },
    c: 'not changed',
  },

  1: 'not changed',
};
console.log('remove 0', omit(state, ['0']));
console.log('remove 0,b', omit(state, ['0', 'b']));
console.log(
  'remove 0,b,title',
  omit(state, ['0', 'b', 'title'])
);
```